# React autocomplete component within a modal

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, modal-dialog, reactjs

I'm trying to construct a modal width an autocomplete input on it.

I have tried with react-typeahead and react-autocomplete but looks like the have some issues.

Have anyone of you have this experience like me?

I'm using "react": "^0.13.3"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out http://react-autosuggest.js.org

Comment: react-autosuggest works just nicely, I also had some problems with react-typeahead and react-autocomplete